# Finding the last two digits of $6543^{210}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have to find the last two digits of $6543^{210}$, my strategy is to use the Euler theorem and then some algebra to reduce this to $6543^{10}$, however I can't think of any easy way to proceed after this, any ideas?

Comment: $43^8 \equiv 1 \bmod(100)$. I just found this by trial though. Hence, $6543^{210} \equiv 43^{210} \bmod(100) \equiv 43^{2} \bmod(100) \equiv 49 \bmod(100)$

Comment: Related: [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One can use the binomial theorem (thrice). To do so, write $h$ for everything that is a multiple of $100$, possibly varying from line to line.

Since $6543=43+h$, one knows that
$$
6543^{210}=(43+h)^{210}=43^{210}+h.
$$
Now,
$$
43^{210}=(3+40)^{210}=3^{210}+210\cdot3^{209}\cdot40+h=3^{210}+h.
$$
Finally,
$$
3^{210}=9^{105}=(-1+10)^{105}=-1+105\cdot10+h=1049+h=49+h,
$$
that is, $6543^{210}=49+$ some multiple of $100$.

Comment: +1 for the nice little trick to evaluate $3^{210} \bmod 100$.

Comment: @Sivaram, yes, like a toddler anxiously clutching its parent's hand, I put as many powers of 10 in the picture as I could.

Comment: who is toddler ? why is he/she anxious?

Comment: Because it is afraid of falling on the ground/failing to find the last two digits of $6543^{210}$. (And we are all toddlers in the realm of *la mathématique*, aren't we?)

Comment: well,I am just an infant :)

Answer (score 8):

This might be the fastest way:  For the last two digits, you want to look modulo $100$.  Notice that your number is relatively prime to $100$, and that $\phi(100)=40$. By [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_theorem) $$6543^{210}\equiv 6543^{10}\equiv 43^{10}\pmod{100}.$$   Here we can try using repeated squaring.  $$43^2\equiv 49\pmod{100}.$$ $$43^4\equiv 49^2\equiv 1\pmod{100}.$$  Since $43^4\equiv 1$, we see that $$43^{10}\equiv 43^2\equiv 49\pmod{100}.$$

Comment: I knew this,this is rather the straight forward approach, but don't you think it's cumbersome for a 1 mint rule problem.

Comment: @MaX: Not really, repeated squaring is the fastest algorithmic way to do it.

Comment: I was commenting on the CRT approach you posted before.

Comment: @MaX O ya good point, that is why I changed it!

Comment: btw, in my actual solution I was taking $6543^{210}\equiv 6543^{10}\equiv 3^{10}\pmod{100}$ and then doing the process... it gave correct answer, was it the right approach?

Comment: @MaX: Depends.  How did you justify $6543^{10}\equiv 3^{10}$?  If you gave a reason for this then it is fine.

Comment: How are you justifying for $43$?

Comment: @MaX Because $6543=6500+43=65*100+43\equiv 43\pmod{100}$.

Answer (score 5):

Binomial Theorem $\Rightarrow\rm mod\ 100\!:\ (-7\!+\!50)^{\large 2+4N}\!\equiv (-7)^{\large 2+4N}\! \equiv 7^{\large 2}\, $ by $\, 7^{\large 4}\! \equiv (-1\!+\!50)^{\large 2}\!\equiv 1$

Comment: this is brilliant!