# Find the last digits of a number raised to a large exponent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How do I go about finding the last digit of $7^{100}$ or the two last digits of $3^{885}$?  what is the general method to solve problems like these?

Comment: Hint: last digit of $7^4$ and $3^4$ is $1$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290394/finding-the-last-two-digits, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86130/finding-the-last-two-digits-of-6543210, or any of several other questions under the "Related" heading on the right. The only difference is what numbers you start with, but the methods are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $7$ and $10$ are coprime, Euler's theorem guarantees that
$$
7^{\varphi(10)}\equiv 7^{4}\equiv 1\text{ (mod }10)
$$
where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. Thus
$$
7^{100}\equiv\left(7^4\right)^{25}\equiv 1^{25}\equiv 1\text{ (mod }10)
$$
so the last digit of $7^{100}$ is $1$.

Note that $\varphi(100)=100(1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{5})=40$ using Euler's product formula, so since $3$ and $100$ are coprime,
$$
3^{\varphi(100)}\equiv3^{40}\equiv 1\text{ (mod }10)
$$
and so
$$
3^{885}\equiv \left(3^{40}\right)^{22}\cdot 3^5\equiv 1^{22}\cdot 3^5\equiv 3^5\equiv 243\equiv 43\text{ (mod }100),
$$
i.e. the last two digit of $3^{885}$ are $43$.

**Edit**: I misread the question as asking only about the last digit of $3^{885}$.

Comment: The second question wanted the last 2 digits, not just the last digit.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: It's not trial and error.  It's $\phi(n)$ = the number of positive integers less than n that are relatively prime to n.  As 1, 3, 7 and 9 are relatively prime to 10, $\phi(10)$ = 4.  Euler's theorem states that if a and m are relatively prime than $a^{\phi(m)} = 1 \mod m$.  (This not intuitively obvious but is a well-known result).  For 3 we have $3^{\phi(100)} = 1 \mod 100$.  But what is $\phi(100)$?  Well, Another not obvious but well known result is $\phi(n) = n \prod_{prime p|n}(1 - 1/p)$.  So $\phi(100) = 100(1 - 1/2)(1-1/5) = 40$.  So $3^{40} = 1 \mod 100$.

Comment: nice, ty for the comment, how do you decide  what can be a good n for ϕ(n) in problems like these? do I use n=100 for finding 2 digits and n=10 for finding the last digit or doesnt that stuff matter? @fleablood

Comment: It's obvious that the last $k$ digits of $n$ are congruent to $n$ (mod $10^k$). To see this, let $n=a_0+10\cdot a_1+\dots+10^n\cdot a_n$ and take both sides mod $10^k$: $n\equiv a_0+10\cdot a_1+\dots+10^{k-1}\cdot a_{k-1}+0+\dots+0$.

Comment: The last k digits in base 10 mean the remainder when divided by 10^k.  I sort of assumed that was obvious.  The last digit of 2345714 is 4 because 2345714 = 234571*10 + 4.  The last 3 digits of 2345714 are 714 because 2345714 = 2345*1000 + 714 and so on.  More to the point, if you wanted to find out the remainder of $12^{2345}$ when divided by $6125$ you could.

Comment: how would I find the two last digits of 7^915 then? since I get (7^40)^22 *7^35 = 1*7^35 (mod100) do I just find the two last digits of 7^35 then? if yes how do I do that? since ϕ(100)=40....

Comment: There might be more efficient ways but $7^2 = 50 - 1$ so $7^4 = 2500 - 100 + 1 = 1 mod 100$ so $7^4 = 1 mod 100$.  There was probably a way to predict that.  Or maybe we are lucky.  So $7^35 = 7^3 =  343 = 43 mod 100$.  Note we aren't so lucky with the last 3 digits of $7^{915}$. As $7^4 = 2401 \ne 1 \mod 1000$.  In this case $7^400 = 1 \mod 1000$ so $7^{915} = 7^{115}$.  $7^4 = 2401 = 401 \mod 1000$ but here I make an educated guess...

Comment: ...$7^4 = 401 \mod 1000$ so $7^{112} = 401^{28} \mod 1000 = (400)^28 + .....+ {28 \choose 2}400^2 + 28*400 + 1 \mod 1000 = 11201 = 201 \mod 1000$.  


So $7^{915} = 201*7^3 = 68943 = 943 \mod 1000$ so the last 3 digits of $7^{915}$ are 943.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\phi (100) = 40$ we have $3^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod {100}$ so $3^{885} = (3^{40})^{22} \cdot 3^5 \equiv 43 \pmod {100}$. Hence, the last two digits of $3^{885}$ is $43$.