# Specific steps in applying the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve modular problem splitting modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to get an idea of how the [Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) can be used to finish up [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/782235/521868), in which the problem

$$7^{30}\equiv x\pmod{ 100}$$

is attempted by splitting the modulus into relatively prime factors $25$ and $4,$ arriving at

$$\begin{align}
7^{30}&\equiv1\pmod4\\
7^{30}&\equiv-1\pmod{25}
\end{align}$$

I understand that the CRT may be called upon because $m=\prod m_i,$ and we have the same $7^{30}$ value on the LHS, but I don't know how to carry it out.

The question was touched upon in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/521868) as the second entry:

> How do I efficiently compute  $a^b \pmod c$ when $b$ is less than $c.$ For instance $5^{69}\,\bmod 101.$

However, I don't see this particular point clearly worked out, perhaps because it is a multi-pronged question.

---

Following [this presentation online](https://youtu.be/PUe_PFI2atg), this seems to be the verbatim application of the CRT without any added concepts or shortcuts:

From @gimusi's answer (upvoted):

$$\begin{cases}
x \equiv 7^{30} \pmod4\\
x\equiv 7^{30} \pmod{25}
\end{cases}$$

rearranged into

\begin{cases}
x \equiv 1 \pmod4\\
x\equiv -1 \pmod{25}
\end{cases}

Given the general form of the equations above as $x\equiv a_i \pmod {m_i},$ the [CRT states](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) $x\equiv a_1 b_1 \frac{M}{m_1}+a_2 b_2 \frac{M}{m_2}\pmod M$ with $M=\prod m_i,$ and with

$$b_i =\left(\frac{M}{m_i}\right)^{-1}\pmod {m_i}.$$

The inverse of $\frac{M}{m_i}$ is such that $\frac{M}{m_i}\left(\frac{M}{m_i}\right)^{-1}\pmod {m_i}\equiv 1.$

Calculating the components:

$$\begin{align}
a_1&=1\\
a_2&=-1\\
M&=4\times 25 =100\\
\frac{M}{m_1} &= \frac{100}{4}=25\\
\frac{M}{m_2} &= \frac{100}{25}=4\\
b_1 &= \left(\frac{M}{m_1}\right)^{-1} \pmod 4 = (25)^{-1}\pmod 4 =1\\
b_2 &= \left(\frac{M}{m_2}\right)^{-1} \pmod {25}= (4)^{-1} \pmod{25}=19
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$x=1\cdot 25 \cdot 1 + (-1)\cdot 4 \cdot 19 = -51 \pmod{100}\equiv 49.$$

Comment: Simpler to use $\ \large 7^{30} = (50-1)^{15}\ $ and then you need only the first 2 terms of the Binomial Theorem, similar [to here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86161/242)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Math SX! You have to use *Euler's theorem* as $\varphi(4)=2$, $\;\varphi(25)=20$ we have
$$ 7^{30}\equiv7^{30\bmod2}=1\mod 4,\qquad 7^{30}\equiv7^{30\bmod20}=7^{10}\mod 25$$
To find the latter power, you can use the *modular fast exponentiation algorithm*, but here, it will be simpler: modulo $25$,
$$7^2\equiv -1\enspace\text{so}\enspace 7^4=1,\enspace\text{hence } \;7^{30}\equiv 7^{30\bmod 4}=7^2\equiv -1.$$
Finally, since $\;25-6\cdot 4=1$ (*Bézout's identity*),
$$7\equiv \begin{cases}\phantom{-}1\mod4\\-1\mod 25\end{cases}\iff 7\equiv 1\cdot 25-(-1)\cdot 6\cdot 4=49\mod 100.$$

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how to interpret expressions such as $7^{30}\equiv7^{30\bmod2}=1.$ I looked up Euler's theorem, and it led me to things like $7^{\phi(4)}\equiv 1 \pmod 4.$

Comment: So you can reduce the exponent modulo φ(4), which is equal to $2$. This means $7^n\equiv 7$ if $n$ is odd, ${}\equiv 1$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: So we left it at $7^{\phi(4)}=7^2\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $7^{\phi(25)}=7^{20}\equiv 1 \pmod 25.$ How do you go from this to $7\equiv \begin{cases}\phantom{-}1\mod4\\-1\mod 25\end{cases}$ and the subsequent final identity?

Comment: For the last case, I had a shortcut: $7$ has order $4$ mod. $25$,   not $20$, so I simply had to reduce the exponent mod. $4$, which makes the computation, considerably simpler.

Comment: Well, if $7^4\equiv 1$, $7^5=7^4\cdot 7\equiv 1\cdot 7=7 $,  $7^6=7^4\cdot 7^2\equiv 1\cdot (-1)=-1 $, $7^7=7^4\cdot 7^3\equiv 1\cdot (-7)=-7 $, $7^8=(7^4)^2\equiv 1^2=7 $, and so on. More generally  $7^{4k+r}=7^{4k} \cdot7^r\equiv 1\cdot 7^r=7^r $.

Comment: I've come across other posts by you on the same topic, and it seems as though you always go through Bézout's identity to set up the final linear equation. Is that your choice, or something implicit, yet not universally included in explanations of the CRT?

Comment: Well, Bézout's identity is fundamental tool in arithmetic questions, especially through the *extended Euclidean algorithm*, which gives effective tool to compute modular inverses, gcds, lcms. I often use it because many questions are  ’How do I compute, or solve, this or that’, and there are not so many general tools. But I also gave some purely conceptual answers, which do not use this identity (e.g.  proving that  $\sqrt n$ can be rational only if $n$ is a perfect square  – which requires only knowing that any non-empty subset of $\mathbf N$ has a smallest element).

Answer (score 4):

$$7^{30}\equiv x\pmod{ 100}$$

Could be solved easily without Chinese Remainder Theorem. Note that $7^4=2401 \equiv 1\pmod {100} $   Thus $$ 7^{30} = 7^{28}\times 49 \equiv 49 \pmod {100}$$

Solving the system with Chinese Remainder Theorem requires finding a linear combination of $25$ and $4$ to equal 1.

Such a combination is $$ 1= 1(25) -6(4) $$

Therefore the answer to the system is $$ x\equiv (1)(1)(25) +(-1)(-6)(4) \pmod {100}$$

That is    $$ x\equiv 49 \pmod {100}$$

Comment: I am interested in finding out how the equation $x\equiv(1)(1)(25)+(−1)(−6)(4)(\pmod100)$ comes about.

Comment: since 1=1(25)-6(4) , in order to find an x which is  equal 1 mod 4 we simply multiply  1(25) by 1 and  and in order to have our x equal -1 mod 25 we multiply  -6(4) by (-1)  and add them up to get x= 49 mod 100. It works because of 1 is the sum of a multiple of 25 and a multiple of 4.

Comment: So $1=1(25)-6(4)$ is Bézout's identity and $x\equiv (1)(1)(25) +(-1)(-6)(4) \pmod {100}$ is $x\equiv a_1 b_1 \frac{M}{m_1}+\cdots +a_r b_r \frac{M}{m_r}\pmod M$ in [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html), with $b_1=1$ and $b_2=-1$; and $a_1=1$ with $a_2=-6?$

Comment: Correct, you have the formula for systems in general.

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

From here

$$\begin{cases}
x \equiv 7^{30} \pmod4\\
x\equiv 7^{30} \pmod{25}
\end{cases}$$

by CRT we know that solutions exist $\pmod{100}$.

Then note that since $7^2=49\equiv 1 \pmod4$

$$x\equiv7^{30} \implies x\equiv 49^{15} \equiv 1\pmod4$$

and since $7^2=49\equiv -1 \pmod{25}$

$$x\equiv7^{30} \implies x\equiv 49^{15} \equiv -1\pmod{25}$$

Thus the system becomes

$$\begin{cases}
x \equiv 1 \pmod4\\
x\equiv -1 \pmod{25}
\end{cases}$$

Note that CRT guarantees that the solutions exist $\pmod{100}$ but doesn't give special shortcut to find the solution.

When you can't by inspection (in this case you can easily find $x=49$), in general to find the solution you can follow the procedure indicated here [CRT -Case of two moduli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Case_of_two_moduli)

Comment: There is a formula based on Bézout's identity.

Comment: @Bernard Of course you can use Bezout, what I mean is that CRT is not aimed to give the solution but to prove that solution exist, am I wrong? Of course we can use the method applied for the proof to find the solutions.

Comment: Yes, but there exists an *effective* CRT, fairly simple in the case of two congruences.

Comment: @Bernard Yes indeed it is precisely the link I've given! :)

Answer (score 2):

Chinese Remainder Theorem says:

$$\mathbb{Z}/100 \simeq \mathbb{Z}/25 \times \mathbb{Z}/4$$

where the isomorphism is given by mapping $x \pmod {100}$ to $(x \pmod {25}, x \pmod {4})$. Thus, the class of $x$ is a number from $0$ to $99$ that congruence to $1 \bmod 4$ and $24 \bmod 25$. The numbers $0 \le x \le 99$ and $x \equiv 24 \pmod {25}$ are: $24, 49, 74, 99$. Now which one is congruence to $1 \bmod 4$?

Comment: Thank you. It certainly helps a lot in a big picture kind of way.

Comment: Thanks you for your attention to details.